# Getting time elapsed since read blocking

Tags: c, linux, pipe

Im using pipes and sending data over them. While read is blocking until write finishes in child, is there a way to get the time during the block of the read? Im using clock() to get time.

thx

Comment: What programming language? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: c language......

Comment: I think the solution is obvious after little thinking, so I proposed the algorithm, not the code as a solution.

Comment: Ok, all of a sudden magically working.

Comment: @test: So your "solution" is magically working now, and "my answer" was downvoted. So: What's the "solution"?

Answer (score -1):

So if you have a writer like

```
while (1) {
  write_to_pipe(...);
}
```

and a reader like

```
while (1) {
  read_from_pipe(..);
}
```

why don't you simply get the time before calling read_from_pipe(), and another after having read from the pipe, building the difference? Maybe you could even calibrate by substracting the minimum difference after having had at least on non-blocking read...

However you should be aware that you are measuring elapsed time which may contain an additional component besides blocking time.

Comment: Can anybody explain why there is a -1 on this answer?